# smarty get array key name

Tags: multidimensional-array, smarty

I am using smarty 3 and try to access an array.
I have an array like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Name 1' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Name 2' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
```

I would like to get "Name 1" and "Name 2" and the values of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I reverse-engineered your pretty-printed data into a PHP array like:

```php
$a = [
  [
    'Name 1' => [
      [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ],
      [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ],
    ],
  ],
  [
    'Name 2' => [
      [ 1, 2, 3, ],
      [ 4, 5, 6, ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

The Smarty code to traverse this data is:

```smarty
{foreach $a as $data}
  {foreach $data as $name => $matrix}
    <div>
      <h3>{$name}</h3>

      {foreach $matrix as $row}
        <div>
          {foreach $row as $elem}
            <span>{$elem}</span>
          {/foreach}
        </div>
      {/foreach}
    </div>
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

This produces the output:

---

**Name 1**

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10

**Name 2**

1 2 3
4 5 6

---